# the code used for list box control , i like to use for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen 1 article with below address

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/uploading-multiple-files-with-listbox-in-Asp-Net/

That use list box for showing uploaded files

```
if (ListBox1.Items.Contains(new ListItem(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))))
{
      Label1.Text = "File already in the ListBox";
}
else
{
      Files.Add(FileUpload1);
      ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
      Label1.Text = "Add another file or click Upload to save them all";
}
```

,now I like to do that in grid view, but I have problem to transfer below code for grid view, it has problem it does not prevent duplicate uploaded file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     if (GridViewEfile.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
     {
             Label2.Text = "File already in the list";
             break;
     }
}
```

What I have done for gridview:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
      if (GridViewEfile.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
      {
            Label2.Text = "File already in the list";
            break;
      }
}

for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["File Name"] = GridViewEfile.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text;
      dr["File Size"] = GridViewEfile.Rows[j].Cells[2].Text;
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["File Name"] = FileName;

if (size > 0)
     dr["File Size"] = size.ToString() + " KB";
else
     Label2.Text = "File size cannot be 0";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

GridViewEfile.DataSource = dt;
GridViewEfile.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you do not stop adding new row even when you have found duplicate.

```
bool isDuplicate = false;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (GridViewEfile.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
    {
         Label2.Text = "File already in the list";
         isDuplicate = true;
         break;
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
     dr = dt.NewRow();
     dr["File Name"] = GridViewEfile.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text;
     dr["File Size"] = GridViewEfile.Rows[j].Cells[2].Text;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

if (!isDuplicate)
{
     if (size == 0)
     {
         Label2.Text = "File size cannot be 0";
     }
     else
     {
         dr = dt.NewRow();
         dr["File Name"] = FileName;
         dr["File Size"] = size.ToString() + " KB";

         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
}

GridViewEfile.DataSource = dt;
GridViewEfile.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have wrong nesting - first loop should be file iteration, second one - check for dupes. You have it vise versa.

Check the snippet below:

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) // here is file iteration
{
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // here is dupe check
   {
      if (GridViewEfile.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
      {
          Label2.Text = "File already in the list";
          break;
      }
   }

   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["File Name"] = FileName;
   if (size > 0)
      dr["File Size"] = size.ToString() + " KB";
   else
      Label2.Text = "File size cannot be 0";

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);

   GridViewEfile.DataSource = dt;

   GridViewEfile.DataBind();
   }
}
```